# How to get only lines with a single quote using GNU sed in Bash shell?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, quoting

I'm writing a script to parse a text file (multiple lines). I need to print only lines matching the following pattern:

1. First character of the line is an Uppercase letter
2. Second character of the line is a lowercase letter OR a single quote
3. Third character of the line is a lowercase letter OR a space

## Examples of "valid" lines

- Abcd
- A'cd
- Ab c

## Attemps with GNU sed 4.2.2 on Linux

### I ] First attempt (escaping)

```
$ html2text foo.html | sed -r "/^([A-Z][a-z\'])/!d"
```

Produces the following error message:

> html2text foo.html | sed -r "/^([A-Z][a-z\'])/date"
>
> sed: -e expression n°1, character 19: extra characters after command

### II ] Second attempt (no escaping)

```
$ html2text foo.html | sed -r "/^([A-Z][a-z'])/!d"
```

Produces the following error message:

> html2text foo.html | sed -r "/^([A-Z][a-z'])/date"
>
> sed: -e expression n°1, character 18: extra characters after command

I'm not quite sure how to deal with single quote "'" within a range. I know that escaping a single quote within a single-quoted sed expression is not supported at all, but here both sed expressions are double-quoted.

Weird thing is that error messages both return ".../date" (first line of error messages) which appear to be a bug or parsing issue ("/!d" flag is misinterpreted)...

Note: html2text convert 'foo.html' to text file. sed -r option stands for Extended regular expression. "[A-Z]" matches a range of characters (square square brackets are not literals here)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why didn't you use grep?

Comment: Your first two valid examples have only two characters.. how do they meet #3? Or is it supposed to be a space?

Comment: Actually, your valid lines doesn't match that you stated in your steps since you stated 3 characters long and your first two samples contain only two

Comment: FatalError, Fede: You're right, I've been lazy... Valid lines exampes are fixed now.

Comment: You should submit a bug report against `sed` if your localisation is really printing `°` in place of `º` in its error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by [casimir-et-hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) using grep is simpler here:

`grep "^[A-Z][a-z'][a-z ]"`

or using sed:

`sed -n "/^[A-Z][a-z'][a-z ]/p"`

Comment: @ jineff: I missed the obvious, thanks. Still curious why !d flag seems to produce these errors.

Comment: Best explanation ("!d" issue): http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/

Comment: To work portably you should use character classes - `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` and `[[:lower:]']` instead of `[a-z']`.  That will respect the `LC_CTYPE` in effect for the command.

Comment: @jineff: I guess that using double quotes caused the !d to be expanded as the 'date' command within my Bash history. karakfa answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32255448/998155) is indeed very usefull in that context

Answer (score 1):

if you need to have single quotes for some reason, this can be used to escape the single quote in the script

```
sed -n '/^[A-Z][a-z'"'"'][a-z ]/p'
```